# PlanetScale: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field

Tags: command-line-interface

When I try to connect to my `PlanetScale` database using the `CLI`, I get a `cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field` error.

CLI command to connect to DB:

```
pscale connect <db_name> <branch_name> --port 3310
```

Error response:

```
Error: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field
DatabaseBranch.dev of type bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this issue was caused because of a raw SQL insert that inputted 1 into a boolean field instead of true. Running an SQL update command to replace the 1s with true solved the issue.